# Opera bug always uses window.top?

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I have been lately working a lot on Opera and for now I have been trying to make a tab-able form in which I use a `RTF` too (rich text widget).

My form works fine in FF and Chrome i.e,
I can traverse the whole form and fill it without any fuss but in `Opera` everything works well except for RTF.

Whenever I try to get of an RTF by pressing the tab button it takes me back (read focuses) back to the first element of the form. Also I have added `tabindex = -1` to every element within the RTF widget but in vain. It still gets out of the form and focusses on the first element.

I can't figure out why is this happening?

Comment: 1) RTF in HTML form? How? 2) What's relation between title and content of your question?

Comment: The thing is RTF widget of ours uses iframe to show content and I am getting feeling that when the iframe looses focus it takes the window.top and focusses the first element rather than the next element in line.